# PHP isn't starting server in vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, server

```
[404]: GET / - Permission denied
[404] / - No such file or directory
```

I've tried setting PATH in "PHP server configuration" => PHP Config path and PHP path:
`C:/xampp/php/php.exe`

I've also tried to change server's port number.

In "setting.json" it's writing all pathes:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
"phpserver.phpConfigPath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
"phpserver.phpPath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe"
```

But still isn't working

Also, path in control panel is installed correctly(just copied from folder itself)

Comment: Making everything **BOLD** does not help us in any way. It would be better to spend time making sure the question is well asked and has enought information for us to be able to help. ALso statements like _Also, path in control panel is installed correctly_ dont help as we only have your word for the correctness

Comment: As you have XAMPP installed then use it. Its a better server than the PHP builtin server and you are able to ensure it is configured as your live server will be configured

Comment: That's just all i know, that's why I'm asking

Comment: I'm just new to stackoverflow, so thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that i putted my project file on a desktop and chosed path to xamp folder with "php.exe" in it.

I have just made a folder in "xampp\htdocs", put my project file into that created folder, and  started the server. That instantlty opened me my php file.